# Use Rough.js as a Konva renderer

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

Trying to use Rough.js to render parts of a konva Stage but without success. Rough uses a reference to the canvas to draw to, but neither getCanvas() nor toCanvas() on a konva layer seems to do the trick. Ideas?

```
// Combined code
const cstage = new Konva.Stage({
   container: 'roughAndKonva',
   width: 200,
   height: 200
});
const clayer = new Konva.Layer();
var konvaCanvas = clayer.getCanvas()
const crc = rough.canvas(konvaCanvas);
crc.rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
cstage.add(clayer);
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qwLmb9ge/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the answer by Vanquished Wombat above to get started, but ran into some problems with re-drawing the scene as the new rectangle drawn would then be erased.

Solved this by drawing the rough-Rectangle onto a SVG and then converting the SVG to and Image that can be added onto Konva. This makes it fit snuggly into the Konva JS routines, including redraws.

```
// Background box
  const svg = $('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>')[0];
  svg.setAttribute("height", startWidth);
  svg.setAttribute("width", startHeight);
  const rc = rough.svg(svg);
  svg.appendChild(rc.rectangle(0, 0, startWidth, startHeight, {roughness: 0.3, strokeWidth: 2}));
  svgToImg(svg).then(background => {
    const bgImage = new Konva.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: background,
        name: 'depLine',
        width: background.width,
        height: background.height
      });
    board.add(bgImage);
    board.draw();
  });
```

svgToImg function:

```
// Promise to convert SVG to Image
function svgToImg(svg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    const svgBlob = new Blob([svg.outerHTML], {type:'image/svg+xml'});
    const url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
    img.onload = function() {
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        resolve(this);
    };
    img.onerror = reject
    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and decided to try to make both libraries work with each other.

First, Konva provides a [Shape](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Shape.html) class to create custom shapes. It has sceneFunc() method that can be used in order to draw rough shapes. This is an example from official documentation:

```js
const customShape = new Konva.Shape({
  x: 5,
  y: 10,
  fill: 'red',
  // a Konva.Canvas renderer is passed into the sceneFunc function
  sceneFunc (context, shape) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(200, 50);
    context.lineTo(420, 80);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(300, 100, 260, 170);
    context.closePath();
    // Konva specific method
    context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
  }
});
```

Now you anyways need to create an instance of rough canvas, so it will know that we're drawing on canvas:

```js
const roughCanvas = rough.canvas(document.querySelector(`.${SHAPES_LAYER_CLS}`));
```

This instance will be used inside of sceneFunc().
The next problem is that you'll need to use provided context (first argument of sceneFunc) and rough.js doesn't provide API to draw using the context, but you can do something different:

1. Use [generator API](https://github.com/rough-stuff/rough/wiki#generator) to create drawable object
2. Use [code from the rough.js library](https://github.com/rough-stuff/rough/blob/fd621f41c33996d9bc9334768ed5fd29243e49a1/src/canvas.ts), that can create shape based on instructions from the drawable object and draw on provided context (I keep this code in roughService)
3. sceneFunc() will be called a lot by the konva, so you can cache drawable object and use it in order not to generate new shape on every render.

```js
const roughShape = new Konva.Shape({
    x: this.props.x || 0,
    y: this.props.y || 0,
    width: this.props.width || 0,
    height: this.props.height || 0,
    stroke: '#000000',
    strokeWidth: this.props.strokeWidth,
    fill: 'transparent',
    draggable: true,
    sceneFunc: (context, shape) => {
        if (isSelected()) {
            lastDrawable = roughCanvas.generator.rectangle(
                0,
                0,
                shape.getWidth(),
                shape.getHeight(),
                {
                    roughness: ROUGHNESS,
                    stroke: '#000000',
                },
            );
        }
        roughService.draw(context, lastDrawable);
        context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
    }
});
```

Hope that makes sense. This is link to my usage - [RoughRect.ts](https://github.com/artemdemo/imgreview/blob/369c1c10ad88ed2424d671b9bd5e752332484827/srcCanvas/RectLike/RectRough.ts)

Answer (score 1):

As a general thought, you may get some interference between the libs, e.g. unexpected redraws by one clearing the content output by the other.

You might want to consider having 2 separate, stacked canvases, one for Rough and one for Konva, so that they give the appearance of a single canvas but keep the canvas admin separated for each lib. That may not be possible if you want to overlap objects from the two libs in the z-axis.

Also note that Konva uses a canvas per layer.

Back to your question, looking at the sample info at [Rough.js](https://roughjs.com/), it seems that it wants a plain canvas DOM element, as in their example:

```
const rc = rough.canvas(document.getElementById('canvas'));
```

to get the canvas instance you wish to target. Since Konva uses a standard HTML canvas element, you can use any selector mechanism that works in the context of your page to get the canvas. In your fiddle you use

```
<div id="roughAndKonva"></div>
```

which produces in the browser (can be seen via browser dev tools)

```
<div id="roughAndKonva">
  <div class="konvajs-content" role="presentation" style="...">
    <canvas style="...">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Therefore you can access this canvas element via a suitable element selector. If you are using jquery then the following will get you the canvas element that Konva is using.

var konvaCanvas = $('#roughAndKonva>div>canvas')[0];

You could also use plain JS to select the canvas.

I modified your code as below (combined code section)

```
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
   container: 'container',
   width: 200,
   height: 200
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const rect = new Konva.Rect({
   x : 50, y : 50, width: 100, height: 100,
   fill: 'black',
   draggable: true
});

layer.add(rect).draw();


// Rough.js sample code
const rc = rough.canvas(document.getElementById('canvas'));
rc.rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);


// Combined code  MODS HERE !
const cstage = new Konva.Stage({
   container: 'roughAndKonva',
   width: 200,
   height: 200
});
const clayer = new Konva.Layer();
const rect2 = new Konva.Rect({
   x : 40, y : 40, width: 100, height: 100,
   fill: 'red',
   draggable: true
});
clayer.add(rect2).draw();
cstage.add(clayer).draw()

var konvaCanvas = $('#roughAndKonva>div>canvas')[0]
const crc = rough.canvas(konvaCanvas);
crc.rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

Which produces the output for the combined canvases as below, which is what I guess you are after noting that I deliberately offset the Konva rect to emphasize that both are present.

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly, didn't realise I had to to back to the DOM and fetch it that way.

Comment: Indeed you can - Konva and similar libs are acting as a proxy to give additional capabilities over the standard HTML5 canvas element which always has to be there. The lib will usually inject what it intends to be a private wrapper of some sort in the way that Konva does, but you can always crack open the DOM inspector in your browser to see how it is constructed and then formulate a selector as per my example.

Answer (score 0):

`Konva.Shape()` can create a custom shape, and shape `sceneFunc` will provide `context`, so the problem becomes simpler, we can use [Rough.js](https://roughjs.com/) in `sceneFunc`

below for example create a RoughRect:

```
const RoughRect = () => {
  return (
    <Shape
      x={0}
      y={0}
      width={100}
      height={100}
      stroke={"transparent"}
      strokeWidth={0}
      fill={"transparent"}
      draggable
      sceneFunc={(context, shape) => {
        // for Transformer
        context.fillStyle = "transparent";
        context.rect(0, 0, shape.width(), shape.height());
        context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
        // use rough.js
        const roughCanvas = rough.canvas(context.canvas);
        roughCanvas.rectangle(0, 0, shape.width(), shape.width());
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

but rough will always redraw when RoughRect drag or transform, i think should cache this rect, this is my solution with react-konva + Rough.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-with-rough-snlhjz?file=/src/App.js